# How to find matches between two dataframe rows on multiple columns?

Tags: r

Assume I have two dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame (name = c("Mike", "Paul", "Paul", "Henry"),
                   age = c(20, 21, 22, 23))

df2 <- data.frame (name = c("Sam", "Paul", "Paul", "Bob"),
                   age = c(26, 30, 22, 23))
```

I would like to find which rows present in df1 have an identical match in df2 (in this case there will be one such match: "Paul", 22).

What is the most elegant way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

`merge(df1, df2)` should give you the common matches between two dataframes. `merge` by default joins on common columns in both the dataframes. If you have other columns in the data specify the joining criteria in `by` i.e

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c('name', 'age'))
```

To count the matching rows you may use `nrow`.

```
nrow(merge(df1, df2, by = c('name', 'age')))
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with dplyr inner_join, which I believe is faster than merge:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% inner_join(., df2, by = c("name", "age")) %>% count()
```